# Etiqueta html, para convertir codigo html en texto plano

Tags: html

Lo que quiero esque al tener una etiqueta `<i>`, por ejemplo, me muestre la etiqueta y no lo haga.

Hay alguna etiqueta en html que haga esta función?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No hay una única etiqueta que te permita hacer lo que buscas, pero no es tan difícil de lograr.

Te recomiendo utilizar la combinación de etiquetas [`<pre>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp), para conservar los quiebres de línea y espacios de indentación, además que usualmente esta etiqueta se muestra en caracteres monoespaciados, con la etiqueta [`<code>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_code.asp) para indicar que es código de computadora.

Finalmente, debes utilizar secuencias de escape para algunos caracteres. Especialmente `<`, que sustituyes por `&lt;` y `&` que sustituyes por `&amp;`.

Generalmente también se sustituye `>` por `&gt;`, aunque no es necesario, guarda la simetría.

Ejemplo:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
  <title>Ejemplo</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<h1>Un ejemplo de código HTML</h1>
<pre>
  <code>
&lt;html&gt;
&lt;head&gt;
  &lt;meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"&gt;
  &lt;title&gt;Ejemplo&lt;/title&gt;
&lt;/head&gt;
&lt;body bgcolor="#ffffff" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"&gt;
  &lt;h1&gt;Un ejemplo de código HTML&lt;/h1&gt;
  &lt;pre&gt;
    &lt;code&gt;
  Ejemplo de código
    con indentación
    &lt;/code&gt;
  &lt;/pre&gt;
&lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;
  </code>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Una forma muy pràctica, gracias por tu respuesta me ha aclarado aún mejor las possibilidades de estas etiquetas.

Answer (score 0):

Reemplaza `<` por `&lt;` y `>` por `&gt;`

[Pregunta original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817262/how-to-display-html-tags-as-plain-text)

Comment: Y además se podría agregar dentro de una etiqueta `<code></code>` para indicar que se va mostrar un código.

Comment: Muchas gracias por vuestras respuestas me han aclarado bastante, y es lo que buscaba.